# How to change CAEmitterLayer position without emitting particles in between?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, particles, caemitterlayer

I want to display sparkles for the short period when a user touches the screen (placed at the touch position).

The problem is when I change CAEmitterLayer's `emitterPosition` it acts as if it is trying to animate this position from old value to new one during about 0.5s period, instead of changing it instantly.

For example the emitter position is set to (0,0) by default, so when I try to touch at the center of the screen for the first time, it emits a line of sparkles from (0,0) to current position, instead of emitting sparkles form the center.

To stop sparkles, I set layer's `birthRate` to 0 after a short delay, then on touch I change `emitterPosition` and turn `birthRate` back to 1.

The only solution I could find is to have 0.5s delay between moving the position and turning `birthRate` on.

```
- (void)initSparkles {
    layer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
    layer.birthRate = 0;
    [sparkleView.layer addSublayer:layer];
}

- (void)showSparkles:(CGPoint)position {
    layer.emitterPosition = position;

    CAEmitterCell *sparkle = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    sparkle.props = ...;

    layer.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sparkle, nil];
    layer.birthRate = 1.0;

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopSparkles) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05 ];
}

- (void)stopSparkles {
    layer.birthRate = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running any animations? Show the code for moving the emitter.

Comment: @Wain Added some code. Don't have any animations running.

Comment: No animations anywhere? Maybe in a method that calls `showSparkles`?

Comment: @Wain I had one `[UIView animateWithDuration]` but I commented it out to be sure, same thing. I assume this layer emitter itself is an aways running animation, isn't it. By changing birthRate it doesn't really stop it.

Comment: Changing `birthRate` can stop new 'animations' from being started.

Comment: Ok got it kind of working by removing and recreating the whole layer.